# How to connect input and select option?

Tags: javascript, html

i have input like this:

```
<input name="men" id="men" type="text" size="10" maxlength="2"/>
```

and select

```
<select id="menlist" name="menlist">
  <option value="1">Sausis</option>
  <option value="2">Vasaris</option>
  <option value="3">Kovas</option>
  <option value="4">Balandis</option>
</select>
```

How I can connect `input id men` and `select id menlist` with javascrip?
for example:
if user write to input field 2 -> select option value changing to 2;

Comment: what you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried writing any JavaScript yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question wether it's OK to use jQuery. If it is then you can do

```
$(function(){
    $("#men").keyup(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        $("#menlist option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#menlist option[value=" + value + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
    });
    $("#menlist").change(function(){
        $("#men").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/8sJNR/)**

*That way you can have any values for options in any order. Just make sure that they are unique. You can have names sorted in the select for example.*

**UPDATE** Added a handler to change input value when select changes.

Comment: And one more question. Is it possible to make in same page if user first select option then men value is changing?

Answer (score 0):

On textbox keyup event invoke a function which sets selected value of menlist to the  value typed in.

```
<input name="men" id="men" onkeyUp="func1()" type="text" size="10" maxlength="2"/>

function func1()
{
var txtval = parseInt(document.getElementById("men").value);
document.getElementById("menlist").selectedIndex= txtval;
}
```

Comment: dont forget the semi-colon! (I know it's not essential, but good practices must be maintained!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function change_select(val)
{
  document.getElementById('menlist').selectedIndex = val;
}
</script>
```